# Basis for the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x,y]/(xy, x^2 + y^5)$ over $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'd like to find the basis over $\mathbb R$ for the quotient ring $R := \mathbb R[x,y]/(xy, x^2 + y^5)$.
And also find the inverse of $1+y$.

I have tried to take a general $p(x,y)\in \mathbb R[x,y]$ and write it as $p(x,y)=(x^2+y^5)q(x,y)+xR_1(y)+R_0(y)$ where $R_1(y), R_0(y)$ are polynoms over $\mathbb R$. Then we can see that this is equivalent to
$a_0x+R_0(y)$ when $a_0$ is the free coefficient of $R_1(y)$. But I couldn't move forward from here since the basis $\{1,x,\dotsc\}$ is not finite.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I provided a community wiki answer because I feel there must be already many similar questions on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Modulo $xy$, every polynomial in $x, y$ can be written $P(x)+yQ(y)$, and modulo $y^5+x^2$ you can even assume $\deg Q\le3$ (since $y^5\equiv-x^2$)  and $\deg P\le2$ (since - thank you @hunter - $x^3\equiv-xy^5\equiv0$), so a generating set of the quotient is
  $$\{1,x,x^2,y,y^2,y^3,y^4\}.$$
- Let us check that this set is linearly independent (hence a basis). So, let $a,b,\dots,g\in\Bbb R$ and $P,Q\in\Bbb R[x,y]$ be such that
  $$a+bx+cx^2+dy+ey^2+fy^3+gy^4=xyP(x,y)+(x^2+y^5)Q(x,y).$$
  Evaluation at $x=0$ gives $y^5\mid a+dy+ey^2+fy^3+gy^4$ hence $a=d=e=f=g=0$ and there remains $bx+cx^2=xyP(x,y)+(x^2+y^5)Q(x,y)$, which implies $x\mid Q(x,y)$ and $b+cx=yP(x,y)+(x^2+y^5)R(x,y)$. Finally, evaluation at $y=0$ gives $x^2\mid b+cx$ hence $b=c=0$, q.e.d.
- As for $1+y,$ since $y^6=-x^2y=0,$ an inverse is
  $$(1+y)^{-1}=1-y+y^2-y^3+y^4-y^5.$$

Comment: $x^3 = -xy^5 = 0$.

Comment: $\large{\color{green}\checkmark}$ Done. Do downvoters still have any objection?

Comment: It's a good solution.

Comment: (I am an upvoter and have no objection!)

Answer (score 3):

This is a conceptual solution in the sense that I will use some general lemmas which are useful in many other situations as well. In case you don't know them, you should really prove them or look up their proofs, since they will enable you to solve many of these problems.

Let $k$ be any commutative ring. By Lemma 1 below, the ring $k[x,y]/\langle x^2 + y^5 \rangle \cong k[y][x] / \langle x^2 + y^5 \rangle$ is a free $k[y]$-module with basis $\{1,x\} = \{x^m : 0 \leq m \leq 1\}$. Actually I mean the images of  $1,x$ under the projection, but I will not write down the projection here. Also, $k[y]$ is a free $k$-module with basis $\{1,y,\dotsc\} = \{y^n : n \geq 0\}$. Hence, by Lemma 2 below, $k[x,y]/\langle x^2 + y^5 \rangle$ is a free $k$-module with basis $\{x^m y^n : 0 \leq m \leq 1,\, n \geq 0\}$.

Now consider $k[x,y] / \langle x^2+y^5,xy \rangle \cong \bigl(k[x,y]/\langle x^2 + y^5 \rangle\bigr) / \langle xy \rangle$. This ideal $\langle xy \rangle$ of $k[x,y]/\langle x^2 + y^5 \rangle$ is generated, as a $k$-module, by the elements $x^n y^m xy = x^{n+1} y^{m+1}$ for $n,m \geq 0$. For $n=0$ we get elements of the form $x y^{m+1}$. For $n=1$ we get elements of the form $x^2 y^{m+1} = -y^{m+6}$. For $n > 1$ we get no new elements. It follows by Lemma 3 below that the quotient has as basis the complement, which is $\{x,1,y,y^2,y^3,y^4,y^5\}$.

$y$ is nilpotent in the ring, hence the inverse of $1+y$ is easy to find by Lemma 4 below.

---

**Lemma 1.** If $R$ is a commutative ring and $f \in R[T]$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$, then $R[T]/\langle f \rangle$ is a free $R$-module with basis $\{1,T,\dotsc,T^{n-1}\}$, or more precisely $\{\pi(1),\pi(T),\dotsc,\pi(T^{n-1})\}$, where $\pi : R[T] \to R[T] / \langle f \rangle$ is the projection.

**Lemma 2.** If $M$ is an $R$-module and $R$ is a $k$-algebra such that $M$ has an $R$-basis $B$ and $R$ has a $k$-basis $C$, then $\{bc: b \in B, \,c \in C\}$ is a $k$-basis of $M$.

**Lemma 3.** If $V$ is a free $k$-module with basis $B$ and $C \subseteq B$ is any subset generating a submodule $U := \langle C \rangle \subseteq V$, then $V/U$ has basis $\pi(B \setminus C)$, where $\pi : V \to V/U$ is the projection.

**Lemma 4.** If $R$ is a ring and $x \in R$ is nilpotent, then $1-x$ is invertible in $R$ with inverse $(1-x)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$.

Comment: This is a finite dimensional real vector space (as you say, $y$ is nilpotent, so $\{y^n | n \geq 1\}$ cannot be a subset of a basis).

Comment: Thank you. I think I have fixed it.